# Download File From URL Code VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file, download

i would like ask about, how to download file from url by code vb.net? 
example : [Example Link](http://belajar123.com/materi.zip)
before download the file, user **MUST** input Username and Password? how can i do that? any reference or link? thanks!

Comment: You can use a `WebClient`, set the `Credentials` property and call the `DownloadFile` method.

Comment: thank you, please any references or link please @jmcilhinney ...

Comment: How about the Help menu in VS?

Comment: The example link in your question leads to a 404 error. Please check it out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile`

```
Dim remoteUri As String = "http://belajar123.com/materi.zip"
Dim fileName As String = "materi.zip"
Dim password As String = "..."
Dim username As String = "..."

Using client as New WebClient()

    client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(username, password)
    client.DownloadFile(remoteUri, fileName)
End Using
```